# Prevent CodeIgniter of destroy session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm facing a problem with CodeIgniter Session. My application is Ajax based and depends of a user session stored in database to correctly acess and navigate on my webapp. I don't know why but my session is being destroid even defining the *sess_expiration* to **0**. I set session configs like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']         = 'cookie';
$config['sess_expiration']          = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']     = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']      = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']          = 'control';
$config['sess_match_ip']            = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']     = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']      = 120;
```

What I can do to keep my session alive?

Comment: See my solution to the same problem at: [this stackoverflow post][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735456/codeigniter-destroying-my-session-without/22469991#22469991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common Codeigniter issue. I've had a lot of problems with it, but finally it works with this config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 604800; // 604800 = 1 week
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 604800; // 604800 = 1 week
```

Comment: Ok, but I need to destroy session when I close the browser and encrypt the cookie because my aplications suffer many attacks in a day and I need to update the sessions every 120s.

Comment: I think that logout occurs when session is regenerating. So you should probably try any other session mechanism. Google for "codeigniter native session" this can help.

Answer (score 1):

change your config to

```
 $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
 $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
 $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_table_name'] = 'control';
 $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
 $config['sess_persistant_cookie'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Ok, but I need to destroy session when I close the browser, encrypt the cookie because my aplications suffer many attacks in a day, store the session on a database.